# Two conjectures for primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, quadratic-residues, binary-quadratic-forms

Motivated by my paper [Quadratic residues and quartic residues modulo primes](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042120500955) [Int. J. Number Theory 16 (2020), 1833-1858], here I pose two new conjectures for primes $p\equiv1\pmod8$ based on my computation.

**Conjecture 1.** For any prime $p\equiv1\pmod 8$, we have
$$\prod_{1\le i,j\le(p-1)/2\atop p\nmid i^2+6ij+j^2}(i^2+6ij+j^2)\equiv -2^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p\tag{1}$$
and
$$\prod_{1\le i,j\le(p-1)/2\atop p\nmid i^2-6ij+j^2}(i^2-6ij+j^2)\equiv -2^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p.\tag{2}$$

**Conjecture 2.** Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv1\pmod 8$, and write $p=x^2+2y^2$ with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ and $x\equiv1\pmod4$. Then
$$\prod_{1\le i,j\le(p-1)/2\atop p\nmid i^2+4ij+2j^2}(i^2+4ij+2j^2)\equiv (-1)^{(x+3)/4}2^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p\tag{3}$$
and
$$\prod_{1\le i,j\le(p-1)/2\atop p\nmid i^2-4ij+2j^2}(i^2-4ij+2j^2)\equiv (-1)^{(x+3)/4}2^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p.\tag{4}$$

It is easy to see that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$, and $(3)$ is equivalent to $(4)$.

**Question 1**. Are Conjectures 1 and 2 true? How to prove them?

Actually, I also have some other conjectures similar to Conjectures 1 and 2.

For any prime $p\equiv1\pmod8$, it is easy to see that $(1)$ has the following equivalent form:
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le(p-1)/2\atop p\nmid i^2+6ij+j^2}(i^2+6ij+j^2)\equiv\pm2^{(p-1)/8}\pmod p.\tag5$$

**Question 2.** How to determine the sign in $(5)$ explicitly?

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: @JohnOmielan Probably he meant $p\nmid$ instead of $p\mid$.

Comment: Both quadratic forms factor into linear factors over $\mathbb F_p$...